# Disabling button while in use

Tags: javascript

Trying to make a button that loads up for a game onClick, it makes a glitchy appearance when spammed so I tried to use .disabled = true; but this wont work... any suggestions?

```js
function click_01() {
var elem = document.getElementById('trash_02');
var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
var width = 1;
function frame(){
   if (width >= 100){
        clearInterval(id);
        elem.style.width = 0 + '%';
        width = 0;
        document.getElementById('trash').disabled = false;
   } else {
        width = width + 1;
        elem.style.width = width + '%';
        document.getElementById('trash').disabled = true;
   }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="trash_01">
  <a href="" class="trash" id="trash" onclick="click_01(); return false;">
  <img src="trash.jpg" height="100px" width="100px"></a>
  <div id="trash_02"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you include your HTML?

Comment: and relevant css codes.

Comment: what type of element is the element with id = trash?

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/8tqmfL8s/4/

Comment: Are you doing any research at all? You seem to be submitting a question every hour and all related to the same project.

Comment: Their is html, and sorry if i am getting irritable, I'm attempting research and when I use the recommendations it turns flat. Please excuse my ignorance, again I am very new to any form of coding.

Comment: You cant use `disabled` attribute on anchor tags, they can only be used for form elements.

Comment: so what can I do that will create the same effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your finding the .disabled is not working is because you are trying to disable an element that is not a form element.

If you want to do something like this, then change your element to be a form element such as a button, textarea etc